# Unable to rebind draggable events in jqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to use draggable in jquery UI to drag the images .
However , I am able to drag image, disable dragging and enable dragging.

But after disabling the dragging I am unable to enable the dragging again.

Here's the fiddle:

Code: 
`//Please Check this fiddle`
[Fiddle] : http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/yrLbyzfg/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jquery draggable enable and disable method, like this:-

```
  // sets draggable the element with id="dg"
    $("#disable").on('click', function() {
        $( "#im" ).draggable( "disable" );
    });
    $("#enable").on('click', function() {
        $('#im').draggable({
             containment: "#drg"
        });
        $( "#im" ).draggable( "enable" );
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrLbyzfg/9/)